# Necessary torque calculation for rotating a heavy object?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

I'm trying to create something like the image below, where a motor will be connected to a gate/big piece of wood, which will be hinged so that the motor can rotate the gate. I know the weight (4lbs) and dimensions of this wood sheet, but I'm not sure how to calculate the torque required to rotate it. All the other torque calculations assume there is a force being applied, but in this case, since nothing is actually pushing on the wood, would there be no force? Would the force be gravity?

I know the side length of the gate is the "radius" in rotation, and that the motor needs to have enough torque to rotate the heavy gate (which will essentially be sitting on top of the motor), but I can't seem to piece this together into a formula. Here is a rough drawing of what I mean (apologies for the roughness, I did this with a mouse), the gate is supposed to rotate along the vertical axis.

[image]

Please let me know if any clarification is needed, I don't have much experience doing these physics calculations--thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would you want to rotate something large that is not balanced? It will cause other problems. You must define mass , centre of mass radius, rotational inertia, friction coefficient, max velocity, max acceleration, Torque is the force*radius of the accelerating mass around the vertical axis with centripetal mass at some centre radius and friction.

Comment: It can be expressed in different ways https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4fUh.png

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The wood will be attached to wheels for balance (so it swivels easier). I get why force is in the equation, but for this specific case, do I just assume the force is coming perpendicular and do T=F*r?

Comment: For the formulas you sent (specifically looking at the bottom one) I believe it requires the inertia of the rotor (ie. motor specs) to be known--is there a way I can calculate how much torque would be necessary to just rotate the object without having a specific motor in mind?

Comment: The rotor is the entire mass that you wish to define that is rotating F=ma at radius r, so  T= Fr.  Then there are gear friction losses , wheel friction losses.. BTW acceleration is the derivative of ωr